# Question about degrees of honesty

Tags: mussar-ethics, emes-truth-honesty

I have been reflecting on some things I have done, and have begun to wonder whether my 'honest' words were simply a (subconsciously) clever way of gaining a person's trust, and thus of gaining power.

Are there any sources that draw distinctions between different levels of honesty?

Comment: As far as I know, there are not different levels of honesty, but there are different types of lie. You can start by looking here https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Prohibition_to_Lie. It will contain a lot of sources for you to read through. Note, the pasuk says "distance yourself from falsehood". Lying is the quintessential sin, i.e. using an advantage over someone against their will for one's own personal benefit, so yes, you are in the right ball park by asking this question. Hatzlacha

Comment: @Rabbi Kaii - many thanks Rabbi Kaii. I read somewhere that a fool blurts out the feelings of his heart, so please forgive me if this is stupid: I like the answers you have given me here. Blessings, T

Comment: This site will answer many questions about honesty: https://torah.org/series/honesty/

Comment: @Maurice Mizrahi - many thanks, will look into it. Blessings

Comment: Sounds like something you need to discuss in person.

Comment: @N.T. - thanks, I will attempt to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I found something of interest this Shabbat. In Mesilat Yesharim, the Ramchal explains the trait of what he calls "cleanliness", which is basically a level where someone no longer sins, even in the tiniest details of his actions, speech and thoughts. Included in this level is a lot of points relevant to your question. For example:

> ראה נא בענין ההונאה, כמה נקל הוא לאדם להתפתות וליכשל כאשר לכאורה יראה
> לו שראוי הוא להשתדל ליפות סחורתו בעיני האנשים ולהשתכר ביגיע כפיו, לדבר
> על לב הקונה למען יתרצה לו, ויאמרו על כל זה, יש זריז ונשכר, ויד חרוצים
> תעשיר.
>
> Consider the prohibition of Onaah (fraud/deceit). How easy it is for a
> person to be enticed (to find permits - SP) and to stumble in it
> (actual sin - SP). For it appears to him proper to strive to make his
> merchandise appear appealing to the eyes of people in order to make a
> profit from the toil of his hands; to try to speak to the prospective
> customer's heart in order to convince him (salesman talk). He will
> justify himself on all this citing: "some are industrious and profit"
> (Pesachim 50b) or "the hand of the diligent prospers" (Mishlei 10:4).
>
> אמנם אם לא ידקדק וישקול מעשיו הרבה, הנה תחת חטה יצא חוח (איוב ל״א:מ׳):
> כי יעבור בעון ההונאה אשר הוזהרנו עליה (ויקרא כה): ולא תונו איש את
> עמיתו. ואמרו ז"ל (חולין צד): אפילו לרמות את הגוי, אסור, וקרא כתיב
> (צפניה ג׳:י״ג): שארית ישראל לא יעשו עולה ולא ידברו כזב ולא ימצא בפיהם
> לשון תרמית.
>
> But if he does not meticulously examine his deeds very carefully,
> thorns will sprout instead of wheat. For he will transgress and
> stumble in the sin of Onaah (fraud) which we were warned against: "And
> you shall not oppress one another" (Vayikra 25:17) and our sages of
> blessed memory said: "even to deceive a non-Jew is forbidden" (Chulin
> 94a). And scripture states: "the remnant of Israel shall not do
> iniquity nor speak lies, neither shall a deceitful tongue be found in
> their mouth" (Tzefania 3:13).

I strongly recommend learning [the whole section](https://www.sefaria.org/Mesilat_Yesharim.11.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), or at least the parts on theft, for more information pertinent to what you are asking. It seems that, while there might not be different "levels" of honesty, there certainly are lots of nuances and areas to master that are the purview of someone striving to not simply be a good person, but someone who is trying to be spotlessly good.

The above continues and explains to what lengths one should go to ensure there is not a trace of falsehood in his business dealings:

> וכן אמרו (בבא מציעא ס): אין מפרכסין את הכלים הישנים שיראו כחדשים.
>
> Similarly the sages said: "one may not embellish old merchandise so
> that it appears new" (Bava Metzia 60b).
>
> אין מערבים פירות בפירות אפילו חדשים בחדשים, אפילו סאה בדינר. ואפילו
> יפה דינר וטריסית, לא יערב וימכרם סאה בדינר. כל עושה אלה כל עושה עול
> (דברים כה), וקרוי חמשה שמות: עול, שנאוי, משוקץ (מתועב), חרם, תועבה.
>
> And in (Sifri Devarim 25:16): "It is forbidden to mix fruits from
> another field, even if the latter are just as fresh as the former, and
> even if it is sold at a price of one Seah per Dinar and the mixture is
> worth a Dinar and a Tarsit. Even so, it is forbidden to mix them and
> sell the mixture for a Seah per Dinar. 'Anyone who does all these
> things, who commits iniquity' (Devarim 25:16) - five designations have
> been attributed to such people, 'unjust', 'hated', 'abominable'
> ('disgusting'), 'condemned', 'abhorrent'".
>
> עוד אמרו ז"ל (בבא קמא קיט): כל הגוזל את חבירו אפילו שוה פרוטה, כאילו
> נוטל נפשו ממנו. הרי לך חומר העון הזה אפילו בשיעור מועט. ואמרו עוד
> (תענית ז): אין הגשמים נעצרים אלא בעון גזל. ועוד אמרו (ויקרא רבה לג):
> קופה מלאה עונות, מי מקטרג בראש כולם? גזל. ודור המבול לא נחתם גזר דינם
> אלא על הגזל (סנהדרין קח).
>
> The Sages also stated: "if one steals from his fellow even the worth
> of a peruta (small coin), it is as if he takes his life from him"
> (Bava Kama 119a). This teaching reveals to us, the graveness of this
> sin even for a small amount. They further said: "the rains are
> withheld only because of the sin of theft" (Taanit 7b). And "for a
> basketful of sins, which sin prosecutes at the head of all of them? -
> theft" (Vayikra Raba 33:3). And "the generation of the flood had their
> fate sealed only because of the sin of theft" (Sanhedrin 108a).
>
> ואם תאמר בלבבך: ואיך אפשר לנו שלא להשתדל במשאנו ובמתננו לרצות את
> חבירנו על המקח ועל שוויו?  If you ask yourself, "how is it possible
> for us in our business dealings to not try to convince a prospective
> buyer towards purchasing the merchandise and its value?"
>
> חילוק גדול יש בדבר, כי כל מה שהוא להראות את הקונים אמיתת טוב החפץ
> ויפיו, הנה ההשתדלות ההוא טוב וישר. אך מה שהוא לכסות מומי חפצו, אינו
> אלא אונאה ואסור. וזה כלל גדול באמונת המשא והמתן.
>
> There is a great distinction in the matter. For whatever is in order
> to show the prospective buyer the true value and quality of the
> merchandise is good and upright. But anything which is to conceal its
> defects is fraud (Onaah) and forbidden. This is a general principle in
> faithful business dealings.

By the way, if this extremely lofty and awesome level of honesty is making me feel bad, I just remember that Chazal say that In Bava Basra 165a "the majority succumb to theft".

There is further down a section on [giving misleading advice](https://www.sefaria.org/Mesilat_Yesharim.11.69?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), and [honesty and deception](https://www.sefaria.org/Mesilat_Yesharim.11.89?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).